# How can I get a list of threads with a given label id?

Tags: gmail-api

In the gmail api, I have a label id. How can I get the list of threads that are under that label id without getting all of the threads and then parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [threads.list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) and set the labelIds attribute to the label you wish to narrow the threads down to. Here's [what it would look like](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.threads.list?userId=me&labelIds=Label_2&_h=2&) in API Explorer.